# Python urlopen UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

code in python 3.7.4 
when url has chinese character the problem appears.
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(256)

```
import string
url1 = 'http://'
url2 = '医疗器械耗材.cn'
url2 = urllib.parse.quote(url2, safe=string.printable)
url = url1 + url2
header = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'
req = request.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', header)
html = ''
with request.urlopen(req) as f:
    html = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    print(html)
```

Comment: You need add the encoding to parser : urllib.parse.quote(url2, safe=string.printable).encode('utf-8');

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried with your suggestion ,but it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

`urllib` on takes valid URLs, so you'll need to fix it beforehand.

[URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) can only contain *graphic printable characters of the US-ASCII coded character set*. To include other characters in a URL, they must first be encoded with [*punycode*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492) and/or [*percent-encoding*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1). Browsers do this automatically. So does the [`Requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module, which I highly recommend you use instead of `urllib`.

See:

- [An Introduction to Multilingual Web Addresses](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/)
- [URL - Internationalized URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Internationalized_URL)

Every part of the [*net_loc*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808#section-2.1) needs to be punycode encoded (including [*each domain label*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.1) that makes up the *host*). The *path*, *params*, and *query* need to be percent encoded (with `urllib.parse.quote()`.

In your simple case, `医疗器械耗材.cn` is the *net_loc*, and there is no *path*, *params*, or *query*.

Replace this line (`url2 = urllib.parse.quote(url2, safe=string.printable)`) with:

```py
import encodings.idna
url2 = ".".join(encodings.idna.ToASCII(label).decode("ascii") for label in url2.split("."))
```

`url2` is now `xn--ekru7e84uhjb2x6a40o.cn`, and `urllib` will no longer complain.